# Wi-Fi won't work on Motorola Droid

Tags: wi-fi, motorola-droid, connection-issues

I bought a Motorola Droid A855. I don't have a verizon plan, but i was going to use it on Wi-Fi only. I turned off the phone radio, I also turned the Airplane Mode on. After I turned the Wi-Fi on. It showed that I'm connected, but I can't go on the web or anything requiring Wi-Fi. I tried going into the market and it said I don't have a data connection, but I don't need one since I'm using Wi-Fi. So, if anyone has any tips pleae help.

Comment: 1st switch to airplane mode (shuts everything down), then re-enable wifi.

Answer (score 2):

Many phones will show Wi-Fi as connected, but won't work unless Airplane Mode is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi won't work if Airplane Mode is on.

This is because Airplane Mode disables ALL wireless communications, for use on a plane.

On Stock ROM's, Airplane Mode also disables the FM Radio.

Solution:

Turn Airplane Mode off.

Comment: Funny. On my Droid2 as well as on my HTC buzz it works fine the way the OP describes it: 1) turn Airplane mode on, **then** 2) turn Wifi on. Of course it won't work the other way round, as turning Airplane mode on would include switching Wifi off. But once in Airplane mode, I can activate parts (here: Wifi) just fine, while all others stay off until explicitly activated (or Airplane mode turned off again).